# how convert long binary string to character

Tags: java

I have binary string `xl` and `xr`

```
xl = "11110101011100001001011010011100"
xr = "01100101111100011000011000101011"
```

I want to add `xl` and `xr` and convert this binary string to 8 character (1 character = 8 bit). Can you help me to get this code?

```
String Chippertext = "";   
char nextChar;

for(int i = 0; i <= chippertext.length()-8; i += 8) //this is a little tricky.  we want [0, 7], [9, 16], etc
{
    nextChar = (char)Integer.parseInt(chippertext.substring(i, i+8), 2);
    Chippertext += nextChar;
}
Thasil.setText(Chippertext);
```

I have already try this code but the character doesn't same with the character on ascii table.

Comment: "the character doesn't same with the character on ascii table" - what input did you provide, what did you expect, and what did you get? Which "ascii table" did you look at? (I would *strongly* advise against having variables `Chippertext` and `chippertext` btw...) The fact that your first string starts with "11110101" suggests it's not actually ASCII... (ASCII is 7-bit.) If this is arbitrary binary data, this is a really bad way of converting it to text.

Comment: @moffeltje: There's no single encoding as "extended ASCII". There are lots of encodings which are 8-bit extensions to ASCII, but you'd need to specify exactly which one was meant... and even then, that's not the same as being ASCII itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use chars to represent the data of a byte array because there are values that are not equivalent to a "char".

The best solution is to print each byte value as decimal, hexadecimal or binary value.